# A limit with trigonometric functions: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos2x}{x\sin(x+4\pi)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos2x}{x\sin(x+4\pi)}$$
.... and then I got ...
$$= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin^2x}{x \sin x}$$
and I can't insert 0 in that calculation as long as there's x in the denominator and I don't know how to "get rid of it".

Any ideas?

$\sin4\pi=0$ and $\cos4\pi=1$, is that correct?

Comment: so if I use $$= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{sinx}{x}=1$$ i get $$= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2sinx}{sinx}=$$ and then a slution is 2?

Comment: Knowing this limit should be useful here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just continue start by dividing both fraction sides by $\sin x$:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin^2x}{x\sin x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin x}{x}=2\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=2$$

Comment: And is $sin4π=0$ and $cos4π=1$ correct?

Comment: Yes. $4\pi$ radians is

Answer (score 3):

Remember $\displaystyle x\to0\implies$

$\displaystyle(i) x\ne0$

$\displaystyle(ii)\sin x\to0\implies\sin x\ne0$

So,we can write $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac hh=1$ and we know  $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}h=1$

Comment: @user111410, $\sin x=0\implies x=n\pi$ and $\cos x=1\implies x=2m\pi$ where $m,n$ are integers

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the fraction first by dividing the top and the bottom by $\sin x$

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin^2x}{x\sin x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin x}{x}$$

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ = 1, so:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin x}{x} = 2$$